# Auto generate Spring Rest-Controller

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-rest

currently I have the Task to create a REST api onto an existing service layer in Spring.

This is the Setup:

```
@Entity
public class Example{
    @Id
    public Long id;
    ...
}

public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, Long> {}

@Service
public class ExampleService{
    @Autowired
    private ExampleRepository repo;
    public List<Example> findAll(){
        //do some businesslogic
        return repo.findAll();
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/exampleService/*")
public class ExampleController{
    @Autowired
    private ExampleService service;
    @GetMapping
    public List<Example>findAll(){
       return service.findAll();
    }
}
```

The controller is only boilerplate to me and I would really like to find a way to generate it automatically because we are talking about a lot of services and even more functions.

I know there is a way to expose the repositories as REST-Endpoints using **spring-data-rest** but that is not what I want. I want the services to be exposed as REST-Endpoints. Could you please give me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Sorry for the bad code format. I am sure i did everything correctly. I have issued a Stackoverflow support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a Generic Rest Controller which then calls your inner services.
You can achieve this by using external resource file for storing the class details and Java Reflection API .

Comment: could you give an example on that?